# Appending to JSON array with Python results in additional slashes in output file, double encoded?

Tags: python, json, server, client

Im trying to set up a simple python server to read and store incoming user data from a client POST request. Client is sending data in a Json format, and I want the server to append that information to an existing userDataBase.json file.

Client Code:

```
import os
import sys
import json
import requests

userData = {}
userData.update({
    'email':'bob@gmail.com',
    'password':'12345',
    'payment_ref' : 'a34fqw4'
    })
# userData = json.dumps(userData)
print(userData)
url = "<address>:4758/"
response = requests.post(url,json=userData)
```

Server Code

```
from http.server import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler
import json
import os

class SimpleHTTPRequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    def do_GET(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.end_headers()
        with open('gameData.json') as file:
            self.wfile.write(file.read().encode())

    def do_POST(self):
        self.data_string = self.rfile.read(int(self.headers['Content-Length'])) 
        self.send_response(200)
        self.end_headers()
        data = self.data_string.decode()

        if os.path.isfile('userDataBase.json') == False:
            print('Making New File')
            userData = {}
            userData["users"] = []
            with open('userDataBase.json','w') as outfile:
                json.dump(userData,outfile)

        print('Appending userDataBase File')
        with open('userDataBase.json','r') as file:
            userData = json.load(file)
            userData["users"].append(data)
            print(userData)
        with open('userDataBase.json','w') as file:
            json.dump(userData,file,indent=4)

print('Stated Server Listening on Port 4758...')
httpd = HTTPServer(('', 4758), SimpleHTTPRequestHandler)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

This almost works, but the output looks like this:

```
ubuntu@address:~$ cat userDataBase.json
{
    "users": [
        "{\"email\": \"jeff@gmail.com\", \"password\": \"12345\", \"payment_ref\": \"a34fqw4\"}",
        "{\"email\": \"bob@gmail.com\", \"password\": \"12345\", \"payment_ref\": \"a34fqw4\"}"
    ]
}
```

But I want it to look like this:

```
{
    "users": [
        {"email": "jeff@gmail.com", "password": "12345", "payment_ref": "a34fqw4"},
        {"email": "bob@gmail.com", "password": "12345", "payment_ref": "a34fqw4"}
    ]
}
```

I've read around and I think the problem has to do with the fact that I am double encoding the incoming Json data. But I can't seem to fix my problem.

Comment: ``import json; {"users" : [json.loads(x) for x in userData["users"]]}`` ?

Comment: @Sushanth, I think the problem is when I save the file. Because what I am saving is already in Json format. So if I json.dump() a json object, then it ends up double encoded. I tried to save as a string but that didn't work either. The problem I see with your solution is that I just end up with another json object that needs to be saved without double encoding.

Comment: SOLVED!! OK @Sushanth, I think you did/do have the right idea. And It got me thinking. I do need to use json.loads(). But I do it right after "data = self.data_string.decode()". At this point "data" is a string and needs to be a Json object. So I made the next line "data = json.loads(data)" . And now it works

Comment: I guess the problem was not double encoding.